# PHP-5.3.16 Apache crash on image upload / resize

Tags: php, apache

I am using simple image upload / resize function. Once image is uploaded Apache shows "Send Error Report" / "Don't Send" Alert.

Uploaded images are .jpeg and apache crashes on `imagecreatefromjpeg` line.

I am using : PHP-5.3.16

Upload Works with : PHP-5.2.17 version, but I have to use higher version because of code features.

**Does anyone know how to fix this error, or how to make it work with PHP-5.3.x?**

*P.S : I tried to use PHP-5.4.6 but it also shows this error.*

Here is Apache Error Log :

```
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [notice] Server built: Mar 19 2012 19:56:33
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 728
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:43 2012] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:44 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:45 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:46 2012] [notice] Child 728: Child process is running
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:46 2012] [notice] Child 728: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:46 2012] [notice] Child 728: Starting 32 worker threads.
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:46 2012] [notice] Child 728: Listening on port 443.
[Fri Aug 31 22:36:46 2012] [notice] Child 728: Listening on port 80.
```

Comment: At first, check apache error log first. Enable php error logging and check there too.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I updated my question with Apache error logs.

Comment: Not of much use unfortunately. Does it crash on any jpeg image (check if you did not). does i.e. `createimagefromng()` work or crashes too? Do you have image magic installed correctly? if you create test script with just `createimagefromjpg()` would it crash too?

Comment: What is your `memory_limit` set to, and what size JPEG are you attempting to open? Maybe first test it with a tiny JPEG and see if it works. You may need to allocate more memory to PHP.

Comment: Are you using prefork or worker? From what I see it's worker. Worker has the tendency not to work very nicely with PHP. Also, do you have `GD` or `ImageMagik` installed?